# Pass value of stored procedure to Stimulsoft report

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stimulsoft

There is a stored procedure as follows :

```
create procedure [dbo].[spm_report_2]
AS
begin try
  select Temptable.ID, count(*) As CountField
  from (
    select Eductionals.UserID , Max(Eductionals.DegreeID) As ID
    from Eductionals 
    group by Eductionals.UserID
  ) Temptable
  inner join DegreeStep ON Temptable.ID = DegreeStep.ID
  group by Temptable.ID
end try
```

And shows the following output:

[image: Select]

I added this stored procedure to the Stimulusof report file. Now I want to be inserted in a variable of type Stimulsoft Report. such as :

[image: stimulsoft]

I've added the stored procedure to the report file but it only shows the first row ( that's mean `ID = 1` , `CountField = 2`) . How can I generate the top output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think SP does not have this feature.

Use of `DataBand` in StimulSoft